# How detect the two word of a string "appletopic" with a dictionary table in on mysql query

Tags: mysql, postgresql

**I have a table of string like this:**

id code
1  appletopic
2  hellomore
3  maybebasic
Each line is composed of concatenation of 2 words

**and a dictionary table**

id  name  frequency
1  apple  300 
2  you    600
3 topic 23
4 hello 234

**I have to have the resulting table in mysql**

id | code | firstWord | SecondWord
1  | appletopic | apple | topic
2  | hellomore  | hello | more
3  | maybebasic | maybe | basic

If 2 combinaisons of words are possible, the one with highest frequency is chosen.

How to do that in mysql?

Comment: I don't know what do you want to achieve, but I suggest you look at MySQL full-text search for searching. String processing when join two table is not efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a LEFT JOIN:

```
-- SQL wanted
SELECT 
    s.id, s.code, 
    d.name FirstWord, SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.code, d.name, -1) SecondWord
FROM string s LEFT JOIN dict d ON s.code LIKE CONCAT(d.name, '%');
```

The following is a full demo.

SQL:

```
-- data
create table string(id int, code char(100));
insert into string values
(1, 'appletopic'),
(2, 'hellomore'),
(3, 'maybebasic');
create table dict(id int, name char(100), frequency int);
insert into dict values
(1, 'apple', 300 ),
(2, 'you', 600 ),
(3, 'topic', 23),
(4, 'hello', 234);
SELECT * FROM string;
SELECT * FROM dict;

-- SQL wanted
SELECT 
    s.id, s.code, 
    d.name FirstWord, SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.code, d.name, -1) SecondWord
FROM string s LEFT JOIN dict d ON s.code LIKE CONCAT(d.name, '%');
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM dict;
+------+-------+-----------+
| id   | name  | frequency |
+------+-------+-----------+
|    1 | apple |       300 |
|    2 | you   |       600 |
|    3 | topic |        23 |
|    4 | hello |       234 |
+------+-------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> s.id, s.code,
    -> d.name FirstWord, SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.code, d.name, -1) SecondWord
    -> FROM string s LEFT JOIN dict d ON s.code LIKE CONCAT(d.name, '%');
+------+------------+-----------+------------+
| id   | code       | FirstWord | SecondWord |
+------+------------+-----------+------------+
|    1 | appletopic | apple     | topic      |
|    2 | hellomore  | hello     | more       |
|    3 | maybebasic | NULL      | NULL       |
+------+------------+-----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your solution is better than mine! like it :D

Comment: I also thought to use LIKE but I'm not sure can I use it in join or not :D

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have two tables structure like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `codes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `freqs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequency` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And we have some rows of data like this:

```
+----+------------+
| id | code       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | appletopic |
|  2 | hellomore  |
|  3 | maybebasic |
+----+------------+
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | name  | frequency |
+----+-------+-----------+
|  1 | apple |       300 |
|  2 | you   |       600 |
|  3 | topic |        23 |
|  4 | hello |       234 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

You can achieve the possible output with this query below. Basically you have to join two table and check if the substring in `codes` table match with the string in `freqs` table. Notes that MySQL SUBSTRING start at 1.

```
SELECT codes.id, codes.code, t1.name, t2.name FROM codes 
JOIN freqs AS t1 ON 
     SUBSTRING(codes.code, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(t1.name)) = t1.name
JOIN freqs AS t2 ON 
     SUBSTRING(codes.code, CHAR_LENGTH(t2.name)+1, CHAR_LENGTH(codes.code)) = t2.name;
```

The final result:

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+
| id | code       | name  | name  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | appletopic | apple | topic |
|  2 | hellomore  | hello | NULL  |
|  3 | maybebasic | NULL  | NULL  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+
```